# Is it possible to exclude fields from deserialization?

Tags: json, flexjson

I have Entity which contains some fields like id, name, address.

When creating a new entity form a rest call I want to deserializae received json (using flexjson) to the object. But I want to exclude the id field.

I know Serialize has the exclude option, but deserialize doesn't have it. Right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9607463/597849

Comment: I read about ObjectFactory to e.g. fulfill relations. It feels nasty to use it exclude fields completely.